# Cron every 5 second for php script

Tags: php, cron

Is there any better solution for making cron 5 sec for execute php script?

Currently, I made something like this:

1. crone1minTo5sec.php

```php
       $defDelay = 5;  
    
    
       for($k=0;$k<12; $k++) {
       $timeStart = time();
    
       echo "Here my script for execute";
    
        
    
       $timeStop = time();
       $diff     = $timeStop - $timeStart;
    
       if($diff > $defDelay) {
            $wait = $diff - $defDelay;
            $now_wait = $defDelay - $wait;
            if($now_wait >0 )
            {
               sleep($now_wait);
               continue;
            }else
            {
               $now_wait = -1 * $now_wait;
               $loopLess = ceil($now_wait  / $defDelay);
               $k += $loopLess;
               continue;
            }
       }
    
       sleep($defDelay);
    }
```

and crontab -e

- - - - - /usr/bin/php7.4 /var/www/public_html/crone1minTo5sec.php

Comment: `while(true) { doYourStuff(); sleep(5); }`.

Comment: ok, but what's  happend when my included scripts take long time? more then 1 minute.  Does cron run new thread  for php script? Or kill latest?

Comment: First of all you can time your own php script and abort if current time > 1 minute. As for your question I think it spawns a new process every minute.

Comment: cron can do the looping, `@reboot while sleep 5; do cd /path/to/file && /usr/bin/php crone1minTo5sec.php ; done`